# how to write inside a cell of UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ipad

How do I write inside a cell of `UITableView` using `TouchesBegan` and `TouchesEnd` methods?

Comment: Explain,what you what to do  ...

Answer (score 0):

A `UITableView` scrolls and so cells move. What you are talking about would pretty much prohibit a table from being able to scroll. Of course you could have a static table or some other table which never scrolls and so you think that's ok.

In that case, handling touch events in a `UITableViewCell` is the same as handling the touch events in any other `UIView`. You could use a add a `UIGestureRecognizer` to the view and pull interaction that way or access the information through the `UIResponder`.

On thing to remember is, make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is set to `YES` if you are going straight through the `UIResponder` otherwise you'll just end up ignoring the events.